# how to add firebase element to dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I have this empty dictionary

```
let orderArray = ["name":"","quntity":"","price":""]
```

and when i download the data from Firebase, i want to get some elements and put them in the dictionary to read it later

Here's my Firebase method:

```
self.databaseRef.child("Users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("cart").child(self.orderFromKitchen).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //if the reference have some values
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        //clearing the list
        self.ordersList.removeAll()

        //iterating through all the values
        for info in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            //getting values
            //let key = self.kitchensRef.childByAutoId().key
            let infoObject = info.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let name  = infoObject?["name"]
            let Id  = infoObject?["ID"]
            let img  = infoObject?["img"]
            let price = infoObject?["price"]
            let quantity = infoObject?["quntity"]

            self.nameArr.append((name as! String?)!)
            self.quaArr.append((quantity as! String?)!)

            let info = ordersModel(id: Id as! String?, name: name as! String?, img: img as! String?, price: price as? Int,quantity:quantity as! String?)

        //here i want to add name and price to the dictionary
        self.orderArray.insert(contentsOf: "\(infoObject?["name"]!)", at: 0)
        self.orderArray.insert(contentsOf: "\(infoObject?["price"]!)", at: 2)
            self.ordersList.append(info)
        }

        //reloading the tableview
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.loadingView.isHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: var orderArray = ["name": "", "quntity": "", "price": ""]

Comment: if let name = infoObject?["name"], let price = infoObject?["price"], let quantity = infoObject?["quntity"] {
 orderArray["name"] = name
 orderArray["quntity"] = quantity
 orderArray["price"] = price
}

Comment: Keep in mind that `["name":"","quntity":"","price":""]` is *not* an array, it is a *dictionary* as `[String : String]`.

Comment: @ElTomato thank you bro it's working but all elements in "name" for example all over like when i print it i get `namename2name3` and for price `100200300` like that i don't know what i have to do

Comment: @AhmadF ohh okay thank's bro

Comment: Remove the lines with 'insert.'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys i fixed it by this greate extention

```
extension Dictionary where Value: RangeReplaceableCollection {
public mutating func append(element: Value.Iterator.Element, toValueOfKey key: Key) -> Value? {
    var value: Value = self[key] ?? Value()
    value.append(element)
    self[key] = value
    return value
}
}

self.orderArray.append(element: name2 as! String, toValueOfKey: "name")
```

but i facing new problem with Firebase

like that

```
2019-04-03 00:56:48.969048+0200 Ml Matba5[1809:376762] *** Terminating app
due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason:
'(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
*** First throw call stack:
```

thank you guys 
have a good day